# CSS.supports to feature detect fullscreen support

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to feature detect [fullscreen API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen) support.

Using [CSS.supports()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.supports), I cannot understand how to check selectors rather than property/value pairs.
My code looks like:

```
CSS.supports(':fullscreen {}')
```

Please note that feature detection by checking if `requestFullscreen` exists returns a false positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Using CSS.supports(), I cannot understand how to check selectors rather than property/value pairs.

The `CSS.supports()` method and the `@supports` at-rule only support (oddly enough) checking support for property-value pairs, not selectors.

Generally, a JS-based workaround for detecting support for a CSS selector is to feed it to `document.querySelector()` and seeing if that causes an exception — if it does, then the browser does not support that selector. The main problem with this is with pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements that are implemented with prefixes; since different prefixes will invalidate a selector for different browsers, you'll have a very hard time testing for vendor-specific versions of a selector.

Specifically for the fullscreen API, David Storey has an excellent [article](http://generatedcontent.org/post/70347573294/is-your-fullscreen-api-code-up-to-date-find-out-how-to) covering most of what you need to know about making it work cross-browser. It includes a snippet of code that covers feature detection for the API:

> The following code tests to see if the Fullscreen API is enabled using all the relevant prefixes, except Webkit’s version of the old syntax:
>
> ```
> if (document.fullscreenEnabled || 
>   document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || 
>   document.msFullscreenEnabled ||
>   document.mozFullScreenEnabled) {
>   // add Fullscreen API code here. Remember all the prefixes
> } else {
>   // in reality you should use fallback code here
>   alert("Your browser doesn’t support the fullscreen API");
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the standard syntax is used unprefixed as well as prefixed for WebKit/Blink and IE. The old syntax is uses for Firefox.

Comment: I'll check the clever `querySelector` workaround soon, however the code feature detection code that you provided is very similar to what I have currently and it gives a false positive on a samsung S4 stock browser, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Razor: Frankly, if the browser is outright lying about what features it supports then you're not going to have much luck outing it. But do let me know if the selector workaround happens to work for you anyway.

Comment: Tried to run `document.querySelector(':-webkit-full-screen')` and it returns null, which is another false positive. Still a clever idea, although unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use the Modernizr feature detection library for HTML5/CSS3

It has a property to detect full screen : Modernizr.fullscreen

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Modernizr performs a JS [feature detection](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/fullscreen-api.js), which gives a false positive in my case.